# Problem with infinitely many converging subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Knowing that $ \forall $ $k \in \mathbb N, k>=2$, the subsequence $(a_{kn})$ converges, does that mean that $(a_n)$ converges?

I suppose this seems true, but I'm having problems sketching a rigorous argument. I can't just say that for an $\epsilon > 0$ , $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$, $ \forall n >= max(N1,N2,N3..)$ since I have an infinite number of converging subsequences.

Any help?

Comment: Can't you just take $k=1$?

Comment: sorry, k>=2, will edit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Take the sequence $a_n$ with $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is prime, $a_n = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: that's a great counterexample, thanks!

Comment: It was fun to think about. Be prepared to prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers, just in case.

Comment: Multiply all primes, add 1. What's it's factors?

Comment: ^What if there are no primes?

Comment: @Nishant: The product of no primes is 1, so we're still good.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was being silly and assuming that the empty product was $0$.